# accuracy of C_ARIMA_Gradtrans in R stats::arima

Tags: r, time-series

The R function `stats::arima` calls to `C_ARIMA_transPars` to transform the autoregressive coefficients and keep them in the region of stationarity.

The derivatives of this transformation are needed to obtain the standard errors of parameter estimates. They are obtained by means of `C_ARIMA_Gradtrans`.

In the case of an AR(2) model I was working with, the derivatives returned by the latter function do not look accurate. As shown below, they differ from the values obtained by numerical methods (based on package `numDeriv`) and the values obtained based on the analytical expressions that are easy to get for the AR(2) model.

Example for the AR(2) model:

Generate and transform the AR coefficients:

```
require("numDeriv")
# random values for the AR coefficients
ARcoefs <- rnorm(2)
# transformation of AR coefficients
tp1 <- .Call(stats:::C_ARIMA_transPars, ARcoefs, c(2L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L), TRUE)[[1]]
# for the AR(2) model, the above reduces to:
tp2 <- tanh(ARcoefs)
tp2[1] <- tp2[1] - tp2[2] * tp2[1]
all.equal(tp1, tp2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Derivatives of the transformation with respect to the parameters:

```
# based on package "stats"
g1 <- .Call(stats:::C_ARIMA_Gradtrans, ARcoefs, c(2L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L))
# based on package "numDeriv" (numerical derivatives) 
fnc <- function(x, i) .Call(stats:::C_ARIMA_transPars, 
  x, c(2L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L), TRUE)[[1]][i]
g2 <- matrix(0, nrow=2, ncol=2)
g2[,1] <- numDeriv::grad(func=fnc, x=ARcoefs, i=1)
g2[,2] <- numDeriv::grad(func=fnc, x=ARcoefs, i=2)
# based on analytical derivatives
g3 <- matrix(0, nrow=2, ncol=2)
tmp <- 1/cosh(ARcoefs)^2
g3[1,1] <- tmp[1] - tanh(ARcoefs[2]) * tmp[1]
g3[2,2] <- tmp[2]
g3[2,1] <- -tanh(ARcoefs[1]) * tmp[2]
```

The second and third methods match each other but differ with the result obtained with `C_ARIMA_Gradtrans`.

```
all.equal(g2, g3)
# [1] TRUE
# output for ARcoefs = c(0.7, -0.4)
all.equal(g2, g1)
# [1] "Mean relative difference: 0.0004672373"
# output for ARcoefs = c(0.7, -0.4)
all.equal(g3, g1)
# [1] "Mean relative difference: 0.0004672373"
```

Looking at the [source code](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/src/arima.c), it is not straightforward to me to find out which approach or operations are involved (numerical or analytical derivatives).

It is strange that cosh (which is part of the derivative of tanh employed in the transformation) is not used. Also, a variable `eps` defined as `1e-3` is used, but this does not show up in the analytical derivatives. Maybe cosh is computed by other (less accurate) means?

Is there any reason explaining the less accurate results shown above?

Comment: it would be best to use `set.seed` before you call `rnorm`, or show the values of `ARcoefs` so that your example can be reproduced exactly.

Comment: ... oops, I see that you do give reproducible values `ARcoefs=c(0.7,0.4)` farther down ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Should be a comment but written as an answer for formatting ...)

It looks like this block is indeed computing finite differences with an epsilon of 1e-3 (defined just above):

```
for (int i = 0; i < mp; i++) w1[i] = raw[i];
partrans(mp, w1, w2);           /* transform raw (w1) to w2 */
for (int i = 0; i < mp; i++) {
    w1[i] += eps;
    partrans(mp, w1, w3);       /* w3 = trans(w1+eps) */
    for (int j = 0; j < mp; j++)  /* calc derivative */
         A[i + j*n] = (w3[j] - w2[j])/eps;
    w1[i] -= eps;               /* restore value of w1 */
}
```

I wonder if the simple analytical expressions that you can use for AR(2) break down/get too unwieldy for higher-order AR models?

I would suggest that the next debugging step (not easy, unless you're already set up for it) would be to compile a standalone version of `ARIMA_Gradtrans` with a smaller value of `eps` to see if that helps in this case ...

Or use `numDeriv::grad()` with `method="simple", method.args=list(eps=1e-3)` and see if it matches the `ARIMA_Gradtrans` result.

Following your code above:

```
g2A <- t(jacobian(fnc,ARcoefs))
g2B <- t(jacobian(fnc,ARcoefs,
        method="simple",method.args=list(eps=1e-3))
all.equal(g1,g2A)   ## as before
## [1] "Mean relative difference: 0.000467239"
all.equal(g1,g2B)
## [1] TRUE
all.equal(g2B,g3)
## [1] "Mean relative difference: 0.000467239"
all.equal(g2A,g3)
## [1] TRUE
```

The next question is whether a relative difference of 5e-4 is actually important for your application ...

Comment: Your example shows that numerical derivatives are used. Analytical derivatives can be obtained for higher order AR models, but I don't know if a general pattern would arise in those expressions, so maybe it is not straightforward to implement for a general AR(p). Also, for multiplicative seasonal models the analytical derivatives may get a bit cumbersome.

Comment: A difference of around 5e-4 on average does not seem too much, but for the AR(2) model I will stick to the analytical derivatives.